# Javascript syntax and HTML entities

Tags: javascript, html

I work on some crawler software of my own and one of my users just reported it will not work with code like this:

```
onclick="document.location.href = &#39;http://www.example.com/somepage.aspx&#39;; return false;"
```

i.e. **inside** Javascript code use `&#39;` instead of `'` to designate start end end of string

What surprises me is that browsers I have tested do not report any JavaScript syntax errors... And it seems to work when I click at it... I must be having a brain meltdown - is `&#39;` around a string really legitimate Javascript code?

Comment: JS uses both `'` and `"` for string delimiters ... newer JS also has the backquote ` available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is `&#39;` around a string really legitimate Javascript code?

No. The browser will decode the character references before evaluating the value as JavaScript.

Comment: I understand that browsers decode character references in HTML part. But at this point here: -- onclick="document.location.href -- the browser has entered into script code? It seems very non-intuitive to me that a browser applies decoding of character references here - to the degree I was more inclined to think browser JS engines had added some extended sugar :) - but if it is part of a specification, I guess there is a good reason for it and I have to match it.

Comment: I could only repeat what I already said in the answer. The code is only evaluated *after* the references are decoded. I.e. the browser gets the value of the attribute, not caring about what the content is, decodes all references and then processes it further. I cannot tell you *when* exactly inline properties are evaluated, but if you retrieve the attribute value of a DOM element, you will see that the value is already decoded:  https://jsfiddle.net/3a6yxqtL/